# spring-data-redis: Unexpected end of stream exception

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-redis

Been getting random "unexpected end of stream" exceptions. Load on server (AWS Elasticache) is minimal. There are bursty loads on the client side at the time but the exception doesn't always happen.

```
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_73]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_73]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.23.jar!/:8.0.23]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_73]
Caused by: org.springframework.data.redis.RedisConnectionFailureException: Unexpected end of stream.; nested exception is redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: Unexpected end of stream.
at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisExceptionConverter.convert(JedisExceptionConverter.java:47) ~[spring-data-redis-1.6.2.RELEASE.jar!/:1.6.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisExceptionConverter.convert(JedisExceptionConverter.java:36) ~[spring-data-redis-1.6.2.RELEASE.jar!/:1.6.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.redis.PassThroughExceptionTranslationStrategy.translate(PassThroughExceptionTranslationStrategy.java:37) ~[spring-data-redis-1.6.2.RELEASE.jar!/:1.6.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.redis.FallbackExceptionTranslationStrategy.translate(FallbackExceptionTranslationStrategy.java:37) ~[spring-data-redis-1.6.2.RELEASE.jar!/:1.6.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnection.convertJedisAccessException(JedisConnection.java:210) ~[spring-data-redis-1.6.2.RELEASE.jar!/:1.6.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnection.exists(JedisConnection.java:781) ~[spring-data-redis-1.6.2.RELEASE.jar!/:1.6.2.RELEASE]
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor74.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
at org.springframework.data.redis.core.CloseSuppressingInvocationHandler.invoke(CloseSuppressingInvocationHandler.java:57) ~[spring-data-redis-1.6.2.RELEASE.jar!/:1.6.2.RELEASE]
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy126.exists(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.data.redis.cache.RedisCache$AbstractRedisCacheCallback.waitForLock(RedisCache.java:460) ~[spring-data-redis-1.6.2.RELEASE.jar!/:1.6.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.redis.cache.RedisCache$AbstractRedisCacheCallback.doInRedis(RedisCache.java:423) ~[spring-data-redis-1.6.2.RELEASE.jar!/:1.6.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate.execute(RedisTemplate.java:191) ~[spring-data-redis-1.6.2.RELEASE.jar!/:1.6.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate.execute(RedisTemplate.java:153) ~[spring-data-redis-1.6.2.RELEASE.jar!/:1.6.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate.execute(RedisTemplate.java:141) ~[spring-data-redis-1.6.2.RELEASE.jar!/:1.6.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.redis.cache.RedisCache.get(RedisCache.java:105) ~[spring-data-redis-1.6.2.RELEASE.jar!/:1.6.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.redis.cache.RedisCache.get(RedisCache.java:90) ~[spring-data-redis-1.6.2.RELEASE.jar!/:1.6.2.RELEASE]
```

Is this something I can fix by changing the client pool config? When I have too few workers in the client pool I usually get another kind of exception, not the "end of stream" exception.

Comment: `Unexpected end of stream` can occur due to either timeout issues (see [Jedis issue tracker](https://github.com/xetorthio/jedis/issues/1029)) or concurrent access to the Jedis instance. Do you use connection pooling? Do you also use Spring Data Redis with things like `scan` commands? You also might want to upgrade to Spring Data Redis 1.7 and Jedis 2.8.1.

Comment: @mp911de thanks. We have jedia pools, sure. I upgraded Jedis to 2.9 and had no effect. Does spring-data-redis use its own jedis that is only upgraded if I upgrade the artifact as well?

Comment: @mp911de Our connection count at one of these exceptions, for example, was 30, as reported by the server. We have a pool of 250 threads per instance and a timeout of 500 milliseconds. It shouldn't be stressing the server at all. However, testOnBorrow and testOnIdle are both false. Is it the case that one of the threads in the pool has a bad connection but wasn't closed because the connection isn't being pinged?

Comment: It looks like a connection is broken but still in the pool. Enable `testOnBorrow` so the pool will only return healthy connections.

Comment: @mp911de thanks, your comment made me realize i was using a single instance of jedis from multiple threads

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the redis pub sub mechanism then one of the possible reaosns for this error is because of the limit of data output buffer set in the configuraiton of redis.

If the data throughput is going larger than the limit set in the configuration the java redis connection will fail as it reaches maximum limit so you need to change the configureation of the client maximum output buffer value for pub sub channel and then this issue resolves

> client-output-buffer-limit pubsub

similary there are config for buffer limit of normal client and replication. Normal Client has no limits where as replication has certain limits.